# Not imputing items into my array properly

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

```
var list = ""
var items = [];
var item=[];
var counter = 1;
var savedCount= 0;
var useSaved=false;
var bbPos = []
var used =[]
var needed=25;
var used=false;
var rnum=Math.floor(Math.random()*needed);
var done =false
var counterR = 0;
var round1=true;
var usedNum = false;

function freeSpace(){
  if(items[25]!=null){
    alert("you have to many items for a free space")
  }
  else{
    needed=24
 if(document.getElementById("freeSpacer").value == "yes"){ 
   document.getElementById("freeSpacer").value = "no"
   bbPos[13] = "Free Space!"
 }
  else{
    document.getElementById("freeSpacer").value = "yes"
}
  
}
}
function enter(){
  if(counter<=needed){
    if(useSaved==true){
      items[counter] =  document.getElementById("items").value;
  document.getElementById("items").value = ""; 
  document.getElementById("item"+counter).innerHTML =  counter + ". " +items[counter];
  counter=savedCount;
    }
    else{
  items[counter] = 
  document.getElementById("items").value;
  document.getElementById("items").value = ""; 
  document.getElementById("item"+counter).innerHTML =  counter + ". " +items[counter];
  counter+=1;
    }
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="You are out of room for your bingo board";
  }
}

function start(){

  if(items[needed]!=null){
    counter =1;
    for(i=0;i<=needed;i++){
      checker1();
      document.getElementById("box"+counter).innerHTML= used[i];
      counter+=1;
    }
   
  }
  else{
    alert("you do not have enough items to fill your board");
  }
}
function checker1(){
  needed-=1;
  rnum=Math.floor(Math.random()*needed);
  needed+=1;
  for(i=0;i<needed;i++){
    if(rnum==used[i]){
      usedNum=true;
    }
    else{
      usedNum=false;
    }
  }
  if(usedNum==true){
    checker1();
  }
  else if(usedNum==false){
   used[counterR]=rnum;
   counterR+=1;
  }
  
  
}
```

Bassicaly I think my issue lies in the checker function. Whats supposed to happen is a for loop runs checker however many times it needs (25 or 24) to set that many random numbers into an array and check if that number has been used. Instead what happens is only the 0 posistion is set to undefined and im extremely confused why. Pardon my exsessive variable usage and crappy code. If anyone knows why this is happening it would be appreciated

Comment: You'd get more replies if you would break your question down into smaller chunks. You've posted a pretty sizable chunk of code. But more than likely the issue is coming from one specific section of your code. If you break it down into smaller chunks, you will, 1) be more likely to get the help you want and 2) be more likely to solve the problem without anyone's assistance. Stick to the relevant parts of your code. And try to be specific about what your code is doing. Why 25 or 24 times? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Having said that, if the value of your array at the 0th index is undefined and values after it are not undefined then you're probably skipping over it on your first iteration of the loop. That's just a guess, I don't have the bandwidth to parse all that right now but i'd look in your `checker` function.